# Subversion Merge "Path Not Found"

Tags: svn, subclipse

In my Subversion project I have branched from the trunk, made some changes and I am now reintegrating that branch back onto the trunk.  When I try to do the merge, I get the following error message, which appears to be complaining about a particular revision.

```
Merge status operation failed.
Filesystem has no item
svn: '/svn/repo/!svn/rvr/24066/path/to/branch/newProject' path not found
```

Note: The branch was created at revision 24068.

Can anyone explain why this error occurs and how it can be resolved?

**EDIT**

The version of SVN and Subclipse I am using is 1.6.

Comment: Show real commands, (log, ls, merge) and output and add SVN version

Comment: @LazyBadger apologies, this question was posted not to solve my specific problem, but to act as a resource for this problem in general.  Perhaps I am wrong for thinking in generalistic terms, but from my research it seems to be a fairly common problem with no clear-cut explanation.  Edited with svn version, as that could indeed be relevent information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who happens to stumble upon this question, here is a few things that I have picked up since posting this question:

1. Check the path it is saying doesn't exist actually exists, svn is usually right about these things.
2. It can sometimes be a case sensitivity issue, so check for those rogue capitalisation mistakes.
3. If you are using svn over http, paste the url into your browser and check that you can see the file.
4. Try doing a `svn cleanup` or in eclipse Team > Cleanup.  This is designed for removing locks which are left from when an operation doesn't complete successfully, it has fixed a few head scratchers for me in the past!
5. Check for rogue svn.info files.  This file should exist in the root of your branch, and can sometimes cause problems if it exists in other areas of the project and isn't kept up to date.  I saw this problem at work on 26/06/15 with svn 1.8 and eclipse with subversive and the svnkit 1.8 connector, which was preventing us from merging.  The solution was to delete all the svn.info files except the one in the root of the project.

Comment: Follow ConMan's advice regarding the path existence.  You may say to yourself "Of course the path is there.  This is a 'working directory' for the repository, afterall."  However, one of your esteemed colleagues may have gone and reconfigured the repository directories so your working directory is inconsistent.  Ask me how I know. :-/

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and found that it was caused by one of the Cached Repositories in TortoiseSVN.

To fix it I went to TortoiseSVN Settings, Log Caching > Cached Repositories and deleted the cache.

[image: SVN Cached Repository]

Comment: I dont often use tortoise, but when I do I find its better to disable its caching and saved data.  Been locked out of my account a few times because it thinks it knows the password I just changed...

Comment: Solved problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error doing "show log" on a branch.
Clearing the cache as msmucker0527 described cleared the issue for me.
Actually did "Update" of the cache log, rather than "Delete".
Found "Settings" under Start / TortoiseSVN / Settings

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact error while I was running a svn command. Initially used a batch file to run the command and had no issues. But later I moved to Powershell to execute the command and I would face this error.

Turned out that the URL is case sensitive when executed via Powershell but it went fine with a batch script.

Please check the url for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked out the project as normal project(not as maven project)
and then convert it to maven before team merge. the problem is resolved.